# Best way to find all hard links to a directory

Tags: hardlink

I am tracking down what may be a stray or erroneous hard link to a directory, 
so I want to find all the hard links to a directory to manually verify them. (`fsck` finds no errors, but the link count appears wrong on casual inspection.)

The normal way to check for hard links to a file is to use `find`, either `find -inum` or `find -samefile`, but neither of those work for directories:

```
user$ find . -links 3 -name '.*' -ls
user$ ls bar
l1/
user$ ls -iad bar
10541088 bar/
user$ ls -iad bar/.
10541088 bar/./
user$ ls -iad bar/l1/..
10541088 bar/l1/../
user$ find . -inum 10541088 -ls
10541088        0 drwxr-xr-x    3 user             admin                 102 Mar 17 11:36 ./bar
user$ find . -samefile bar -ls
10541088        0 drwxr-xr-x    3 user             admin                 102 Mar 17 11:36 ./bar
```

Note that although `bar`, `bar/.`, and `bar/l1/..` all are hard links to the same inode, `find` only lists one of them.

I can use `ls -aiR / | grep 10541088` and that will at least find the dot and dot dot links, but I am not positive that there is not some other kind of hidden file that this will miss, plus `ls` will cross devices, which I do not want.

Is there a better way to find *all* the hard links to a directory?

Comment: Current Linux filesystems do *not* allow hardlinks to directories...

Comment: @shodanshok All linux systems allow hardlinks to directories. As you can see from what I posted, the inode 10541088 represents a directory and it has 3 hardlinks to it.

Comment: No for any [remotely recent Linux distribution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210741/why-are-hard-links-not-allowed-for-directories). Also check [ln manpage's](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) notes about `-F`. Can you show your operating system version?

Comment: No, hard links to directories are not possible, barring filesystem corruption. They are explicitly not allowed. Further, the output you pasted does not demonstrate the existence of a hard link. Rather, you have simply referenced the same directory three different times.

Comment: @MichaelHampton having different names referring to the same inode is the definition of having hard links. The names `.` and `..` are always hard links. And I am looking for filesystem corruption that `fsck` missed.

Comment: `.` and `..` do not really count. Is there something else?

Answer (score 1):

Having a count of 3 is correct , when you have one sub-directory .

If a directory have 5 sub-directories , you must have a count of 7 .

In this example i suppose that **/usr/bin/** does not have a sub-directory

If you consider **/usr/bin** the number of reference is 2 .

- reference 1 is `bin`  in directory **/usr**
- reference 2 is `.`    in directory **/usr/bin**

If you consider **/usr/** the number of reference is 3 .

- reference 1 is `/usr`  in directory **/**
- reference 2 is `.`     in directory **/usr**
- reference 3 is `..`     in directory **/usr/bin**

If you consider **/var/cache/man/** the number of reference is 26 .

- reference 1 is `man`  in directory **/var/cache**
- reference 2 is `.`     in directory **/var/cache/man**
- reference 3 is `..`     in directory **/var/cache/man/cs**
- reference 4 is `..`     in directory **/var/cache/man/da**
- reference 5 is `..`     in directory **/var/cache/man/es**
- ../..

Comment: Yes, in the example I gave, the link count is correct. My point was that `find` would not establish that the link count is correct, it would find only 1 link. I'm looking for something better than `ls -R` to find all the links.

Comment: @OldPro , in fact links = 3 is not always true  .

Comment: Why are you talking about how many links there should be? That has nothing to do with my question.